# vue-client-recaptcha error in Vue js page

Tags: vue.js, captcha

I have a Laravel + Vue js (with Vite)

In one page I need to use vue-client-recaptcha (https://bestofvue.com/repo/parsajiravand-vue-client-recaptcha)

Following the documentation at the previous url I installed the module with

```
npm install vue-client-recaptcha --save
```

and then I wrote the following code:

```
<script setup>
import GuestLayout from '@/Layouts/GuestLayout.vue';
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import { Head, Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

import VueClientRecaptcha from 'vue-client-recaptcha/dist/vue-client-recaptcha.es'
import 'vue-client-recaptcha/dist/style.css';

const form = useForm({
    nome: '',
    email: '',
    ragione_sociale: '',
    nazione: '',
    telefono: '',
    privacy: false
});

const invia_form = () => {
    form.post(route('registration.store'));
};


/* pass value to captcha  */
const inputValue = ref(null);

const getCaptchaCode = (value) => {
    /* you can access captcha code */
    console.log(value);
};
const checkValidCaptcha = (value) => {
    /* expected return boolean if your value and captcha code are same return True otherwise return False */
    console.log(value);
};
</script>

<template>
    <GuestLayout>
        <Head title="Nuovo reseller" />   

        <!-- form login -->
        <div class="q-mb-lg">
            <div>
                <Link :href="route('dashboard')" type="button" ><q-btn icon="arrow_back" color="white" text-color="text-grey-7" :label="$t('registration.btn_back')" ></q-btn></Link>  

                    <Link href="/">
                        <img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="/images/logo-ceriotti-200.jpg" />
                    </Link>

                <div class="pt-6 text-lg font-medium text-center">{{ $t('registration.pagetitle') }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div v-if="$page.props.flash.success" class="q-pa-md text-weight-bold" style="background-color: green; color: white;">{{ $page.props.flash.success }}</div>
        <div v-if="$page.props.flash.error" class="q-pa-md text-weight-bold" style="background-color: red; color: white;">{{ $page.props.flash.error }}</div>
        <form @submit.prevent="invia_form">
            <div>
                <q-input outlined v-model="form.nome" :label="$t('registration.field_nome')" class="mt-4 block w-full" />
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.nome" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <q-input outlined v-model="form.email" label="Email" class="mt-4 block w-full" />
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.email" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <q-input outlined v-model="form.telefono" :label="$t('registration.field_telefono')" class="mt-4 block w-full" />
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.telefono" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <q-input outlined v-model="form.ragione_sociale" :label="$t('registration.field_ragione_sociale')" class="mt-4 block w-full" />
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.ragione_sociale" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <q-input outlined v-model="form.nazione" :label="$t('registration.field_nazione')" class="mt-4 block w-full" />
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.nazione" />
            </div>
            <div class="mt-8 text-lg font-medium">{{ $t('registration.label_privacy_policy')}} <a href="/images/PrivacyPolicy.pdf" target="_blank"><u>Privacy Policy</u></a></div>
            <div>
                <q-checkbox v-model="form.privacy" :label="$t('registration.checkbox_privacy_policy')" class="mt-4" ></q-checkbox>
                <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.privacy" />
            </div>

            <div v-if="form.progress" className="w-full bg-gray-200 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-700">
                <div className="bg-blue-600 text-xs font-medium text-blue-100 text-center p-0.5 leading-none rounded-full" :width="form.progress.percentage"> {{ form.progress.percentage }}%</div>
            </div>

              <div class="sample-captcha">
                <input type="text" v-model="inputValue" />

                <VueClientRecaptcha
                :value="inputValue"
                @getCode="getCaptchaCode"
                @isValid="checkValidCaptcha"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                <PrimaryButton class="ml-4" :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }" :disabled="form.processing">{{ $t('registration.btn_submit') }}
                </PrimaryButton>
            </div>
        </form>
    </GuestLayout>
</template>
```

But when I try to go to that page I get this error

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Missing "./dist/vue-client-recaptcha.es" export in "vue-client-recaptcha" package
/var/www/html/resources/js/Pages/Registration.vue
    at bail (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:33869:8)
    at resolve (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:33946:10)
    at resolveExports (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:35321:12)
    at resolveDeepImport (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:35339:31)
    at tryNodeResolve (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:35031:20)
    at Context.resolveId (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:34792:28)
    at async Object.resolveId (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:41349:32)
    at async TransformContext.resolve (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:41114:23)
    at async normalizeUrl (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js:38024:34)
    at async TransformContext.transform (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c842e491.js
```

Is there anyone that can help me understand why?
kind regards,
Matt

Comment: Does your code work if you change the import to `import { VueRecaptchaPlugin } from 'vue-recaptcha'` ? I think you are trying to import the wrong file, since it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the site you posted, does not update with last update for vue-client-recaptcha.
in a new update, you can import the component simply without a direct link.

You can see the document and demo here: **[Vue Client Recaptcha Documention](https://vue-client-recaptcha.netlify.app/demos/)**

**sample:**

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import VueClientRecaptcha from 'vue-client-recaptcha'

import { ref } from 'vue';
/* pass value to captcha  */
const inputValue = ref(null);

const getCaptchaCode = (value) => {
    /* you can access captcha code */
    console.log(value);
};
const checkValidCaptcha = (value) => {
    /* expected return boolean if your value and captcha code are same return True otherwise return False */
    console.log(value);
};
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <VueClientRecaptcha :value="inputValue" @getCode="getCaptchaCode" @isValid="checkValidCaptcha" />
    </div>
</template>

<style>
@import url("/node_modules/vue-client-recaptcha/dist/style.css");
</style>
```